# Accessing checkboxes as an associative array in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following form fields.

I can loop through them as if they were associative, but I can't access them by name directly.

Any ideas?

The form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name=field_group[] value=3> Something worth 3 points<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="field_group['four']" value=4> Something worth 4 points<br>
```

The PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['field_group'] as $name => $field){
                $score += $field;
                $debug_str.=$name.": ".$field."<br>";
}

$debug_str.="\$_POST['field_group'][0]=".$_POST['field_group'][0]."<br>";
$debug_str.="\$_POST['field_group']['four']=".$_POST['field_group']['four']."<br>";
```

And the result:

```
0: 3
'four': 4
$_POST['field_group'][0]=3
$_POST['field_group']['four']=
```

So, as you can see `$_POST['field_group']['four']` is not set, but why since the foreach loop sees it as 'four'?

Comment: um change `name="field_group['four']"` to `name="field_group[four]"`

Comment: It sees it as `'four'`, not `four`. Mind the commas – try `name="field_group[four]"`

Comment: Or `echo $_POST['field_group']["'four'"];`.  Not recommended.

Comment: name="field_group[four]" it did the same thing
$_POST['field_group']["'four'"] did work though,  interestingly enough both times (with and without the 's for the name)
Would there be a "recommended" way to do this?